# Examples where we calculate combinations/permutations using probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations, conditional-probability

The probability of an event $A$ is given by:
$$P(A) = \frac{n(A)}{n}$$
Usually, $n$ is easy to find out, and the only hurdle in finding $P(A)$ is $n(A)$.

However, suppose we are interested in finding $n(A)$. We know $n$ and can find $P(A)$ using some other method (not the formula above), then we can find $$n(A) = nP(A)$$

I'm looking for examples of such counting problems, which can be solved by probability.

Comment: The only thing I can think of which comes close is this proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2813070/177399. Instead of just looking at a single event $A$, I looked at mutually exclusive events $A_0,A_1,\dots,A_m$ whose union was certain. This means $P(A_0)+P(A_1)+\dots+P(A_m)=1$ was relatively easy to prove, while the corresponding combinatorial identity $n(A_0)+n(A_1)+\dots+n(A_m)=n$ was hard to prove.

Comment: thanks for the response. @MikeEarnest. Maybe you can post this as answer?

Comment: This question might also be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3344468/177399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a related notion to your idea, probabilistic proofs of combinatorial identities. Suppose you have mutually exclusive and exhaustive events $E_1,\dots,E_m$, which means that
$$
P(E_1)+\dots+P(E_m)=1\tag1
$$
Multiplying both sides by $n$, you get
$$
n(E_1)+\dots+n(E_m)=n,\tag2
$$
an identity where all numbers involved are integers. Often, for integral identities where all the terms involved have some combinatorial meaning, it is desirable to give a *bijective* proof, meaning you find two sets describing the two sides of the equation, and give a bijection between the two sets. I will now give an example where $(1)$ is easy to prove, but $(2)$ is hard to give a bijective proof for. In my mind, probabilistic proofs are the next best thing to bijective proofs.

Imagine an urn which initially contains a single red marble and a single blue marble. You make a series of $n$ draws from this urn, where after each draw, you put back the marble you drew, plus *two additional marbles of the same color.* Let, $E_k$ be the event that you drew exactly $k$ marbles over the course of these $n$ draws. In my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2813070/177399), I show that
$$
P(E_k)=\frac{\binom{2k}k\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}}{4^n},\qquad k\in \{0,1,\dots,n\}
$$
which leads to the identity
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}k\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=4^n\tag3
$$
I cannot really claim that $(3)$ is hard to prove. You can automatically prove $(3)$ with a computer, using the methods of the book A=B by Petkovsek, Wilf and Zeilberger. Also, there is a pretty straightforward generating function proof of $(3)$. But these proofs lack the intuitiveness provided by a bijective proof, and proving $(3)$ bijectively is famously hard.

Answer (score 1):

The method you cite *requires* the *elements* in the outcome set to *all* have identical probability mass (ie: non-biased weighting) [and, of course, a finite count].

If you *do* have that, then you can indeed use basic algebra to get $\eta(A)=n~\mathsf P(A)$ .

---

I cannot think of a case where the finding the *count* is too much harder than finding the *probability*.  In such a setting, if you can find one you could find the other in much the same way.  They just differ by a constant factor, after all.